# Value of coefficient (Beta1) at different values of other covariate (X2), hopefully graphed

Tags: stata

(cross-posted at http://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1370770-margins-plot-of-treatment-effect-rather-than-y-for-values-of-a-covariate)

I'm running a multivariate regression (outcome variable is continuous, happens to be GPA). The covariate of interest is a dummy variable for treatment status; another of the covariates is a pre-score. We want to look at how the treatment effect differs at various values of pre-score. The structure of the model is not complicated:

```
regress GPA treatment pre_score X3 X4 X5...
```

What I want is a graph that shows what the treatment effect is (values of Beta1) at various values of pre-score (X2). It's straightforward to get a graph with values of the OUTCOME at various values of X2:
    margins, at(pre_score= (1(0.25)5)) post
    marginsplot

I have consulted an array of resources and tried alternatives using marginscontplot, coefplot with recast, the dy/dx option, and so forth. I remain unsuccessful. But this seems like something that there must be a way to do; wanting to know if a treatment effect varies for values of a control (say, income) must be common.

Can anyone direct me to the right command, or options for Margins, to output values of Beta1 (coefficient on treatment dummy), rather than of Y (GPA), at values of the pre_score?

Comment: Pedantic and marginal, but what you present is not a multivariate regression, a term strictly reserved for multiple responses. It's a multiple regression, or just a regression.

Answer (score 0):

Question was resolved at Statalist. Turns out that Margins alone can't do what I was trying to; the model needs to be run with an interaction term. Then it's simple.